# Executing multiple drop table statements in 1 sql file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to drop 200 tables from my database and save the sql statements to 1 .sql file so they can be run in one go on each copy of the database.

I would like to use a separate drop table statement for each table so I can easily reference what line any errors appear on.

I have tried running a query in the following format

```
DROP TABLE schema.tablename GO
DROP TABLE schema.tablename GO
DROP TABLE schema.tablename GO
```

When I execute the query,  I get

```
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
```

For each line.

What is the proper way of doing this that will still allow me to easily locate errors on the tables that are unable to be dropped?

Comment: The `GO` command only appears to work when on its own line. I tried using a `;` after the table name, but that also failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GO has to be on a separate line, or use a semi-colon

```
DROP TABLE schema.tablename 
GO
DROP TABLE schema.tablename;
```

Answer (score 1):

Note in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017)  that:

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the **sqlcmd** and **osql** utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.

So if you are trying to execute this as a single "command" then `go` will not work - you'll need to execute it as separate commands.

If you *are* using a batch command processor, then also note:

> A Transact-SQL statement cannot occupy the same line as a GO command. However, the line can contain comments.

So try putting the `GO` commands on their own lines:

```
DROP TABLE schema.tablename 
GO
DROP TABLE schema.tablename 
GO
DROP TABLE schema.tablename 
GO
```